# Is desert related to dessert

Tags: etymology

I understand that dessert means something like clearing off (table) and desert and deserted seem sort of related to this. But I have been told this is a complete wrong idea.

Comment: You should be able to establish the answer for yourself by consulting a good English dictionary, or etymonline.

Comment: I pretty much put in the question what research indicates -- I don't know if at this point it is a matter of opinion or it can somehow be demonstrated that despite what appears to be a closeness between the origin of the two words, they are in fact not related.

Comment: See here [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=desert) and here [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=dessert)

Answer (score 3):

Etymonline has a good article on these words.

*Dessert* comes from middle French in the c. 1600 (in turn derived from Latin)
a service of fruits and sweets at the close of a meal," c. 1600, from Middle French dessert (mid-16c.) "last course," literally "removal of what has been served," from desservir "clear the table," literally "un-serve," from des- "remove, undo" (see dis-) + Old French servir "to serve" (see serve (v.)).

*Desert*  is derived from *desero* (I desert)  *desertum* means something deserted or abandoned.

So, no, the similarity is a 'false friend'.  they look alike, but are quite different.

Comment: i was thinking "false friend" was an apt term here -- the person who told me i was wrong years ago sounded so sure of herself, too.

Comment: @releseabe I was stretch the meaning of the phrase a bit.  So 'monnaie' means 'money' but only in the sense of physical notes and loose change.  So someone saying he has none of that is not saying he is flat broke!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. Both have a de- prefix, but:

Dessert comes from de-servire, servire coming from servus (slave), which itself comes from servo (keep), which corresponds to οὖρος (keeper) in Greek, and ultimately a PIE root *ver that means "look after", "observe".

Desert comes from de-sero, sero being "to tie together", which corresponds to εἴρω in Greek, and ultimately a PIE root *ser that means the same (to tie together, to make a knot).

Since the PIE roots are different, I think we can conclude that these two words are not related whatsoever.

Comment: But isn't PIE a dessert?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Biganon.  You've given a good answer; all you're missing is citing your sources.  Please take a [tour] and read the [FAQ]. I hope you find good questions to answer!